# Find radius of two concentric arcs

Tags: trigonometry

Consider arcs AB and A'B' in this diagram:

[image: concentric arcs]

Given the lengths of the arcs and the radial distance between them, how would you find their radii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the arc lengths be called $L_1$ and $L_2$ and the radii be called $r_1$ and $r_2$ where $L_1\le L_2$ and $r_1\le r_2$. Additionally let $d=r_2-r_1$ be the radial distance between the two arcs.

We have that the ratio of arc length to the radius is the angle, so

$$\theta=\frac{L_1}{r_1}=\frac{L_2}{r_2}$$
Hence we have  $L_1r_2=L_2r_1$. Since we also know $r_2=d+r_1$, we have
$$r_1L_2=L_1r_2=L_1d+L_1r_1\hspace{10mm}\implies\hspace{10mm}r_1=\frac{L_1d}{L_2-L_1}$$

Finally by applying $L_1r_2=L_2r_1$, we have
$$r_2=\frac{L_2d}{L_2-L_1}$$

Answer (score 1):

The known difference of radii is $\|B^\prime-B\|=\|B^\prime-C\|-\|B-C\|=(\lambda-1)\|B-C\|$, where $\lambda$ is the dilation factor for which $\lambda(B-C)=B^\prime-C$ which is the same as $\lambda=\operatorname{length}(A^\prime B^\prime)/\operatorname{length}(AB)$ where $\operatorname{length}$ is the arc length.

Answer (score 1):

if we take the radius of arc A'B' is R' and the radius of AB arc is R and the radius distance between arcs is x the angle substitute at the center is a,
1.A'B'=R'a
2.AB=Ra
by deviding 1. by 2. we can take,
A'B'/AB=R'/R
As x is known ,
R'-R=x
By solving this simultanious equation R and R' can be find

Answer (score 1):

If you treat arcs like straight lines, proportions are just like in they are similar triangles.

$$ \dfrac{dR}{ds} = const = \dfrac{1}{\theta}  $$

$$ \dfrac{R_2-R_1}{s_2-s_1} =\dfrac{\Delta R }{\Delta s} = const $$

Let $ (R_2-R_1) = \Delta R $ radial distance given,

Apply Componendo /Dividendo relating to fractions on either side to find $ R_1, R_2 $

$$ \dfrac{R_1}{\Delta R} = \dfrac{s_1}{s_1-s_2}$$

$$ \dfrac{R_2}{\Delta R} = \dfrac{s2}{s1-s2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Call $\theta$ the angle $\widehat{ACB}$ (expressed in radians) and $r_1 \leq r_2$ the two radii. Then for each $i = 1,2$ the [length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Arcs_of_circles) of the arc of angle $\theta$ with radius $r_i$ is
$$
\ell_i = r_i \theta
$$
therefore
$$
\ell_2 - \ell_1 = (r_2 - r_1) \theta
\quad \Rightarrow \quad
\theta = \frac{\ell_2 - \ell_1}{r_2 - r_1}
$$
Since by hypothesis we know $\ell_1,\ell_2$, and $r_2-r_1$, we can conclude
$$
r_1 = \ell_1 \, \frac{r_2 - r_1}{\ell_2 - \ell_1}
\qquad
r_2 = \ell_2 \, \frac{r_2 - r_1}{\ell_2 - \ell_1}
$$

Comment: Could whoever downvoted this explain why they did so, allowing me to improve my answer?